# Extracting rows from MS CRM results in duplicates

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm

I have a strange problem when extracting rows from our MS CRM. Let me explain the flow:

I have a SSIS package that extracts data from CRM and loads it to another database. From this database the data is transformed and loaded to a data warehouse.

If this SSIS package runs at the same time as CRM is inserting/updating many rows i get a strange result: The data that is extracted (using a normal OLD DB Source) in SSIS contains duplicate rows (the ModifiedOn date is different though).

If I run the exact same query tha extracts the data from CRM manually in SSMS i get no duplicates.

So.... it seems like the connection from SSIS somehow makes reads of rows that are updated - both before and after the update (dirty reads of some kind).

Anybody experienced this before?

Thx a lot
/Nicolaj

Comment: Nicola, the updates that are taking place in CRM -> are they deletes and inserts? The background deletion services might not have caught up with the items marked for deletion and therefore you might have too many/duplicates?

Comment: the updates in the CRM are a mix of updates and inserts. I'm pretty sure i know what happens now but i can't figure out why: the duplicates i get are allways on rows that are updated. i get both the new and the old version of the row (is this what you call phantom rows?). the duplicates can't exists in the CRM as there is a unique index on the id of the row so it is not the logic of the CRM that is wrong. this happens ONLY when the data is extracted in SSIS. if i run the query manually i get no duplicates. the isolation level in SSIS is left to default so it shouldn't read uncommitted rows.